# htaccess one domain to a specific location in another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I'd like to redirect all requests to two.dev to one.dev/node/10 but still have the url read "two.dev" or at least "two.dev/node/10".  I've tried the following but get a redirect loop error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName two.dev
  ServerAlias *.two.dev
  DocumentRoot /home/websites/one.dev
  Redirect permanent / /node/10/
  <Directory /home/websites/one.dev>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming both domains share the same document root because you have your document root at `/home/websites/one.dev`. YOu should remove the `Redirect` directive since that redirects the browser and will change the URL in the address bar. Replace it with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/node/10
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /node/10/$1 [L]
```

Comment: two.dev is essentially an alias for one.dev which is why two.dev has its document root pointing there.  I made the change, but I'm getting a 500 internal server error when I try to browse to http://two.dev.